# Youtube Plugin for Django Ckeditor Updated

Tags: django, python-2.7, youtube, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I am using Django-ckeditor-updated to build a CMS and I'm trying to use the Ckeditor youtube plugin(http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube), but it is not appearing in the toolbar.

I've downloaded the plugin to the ckeditor plugins folder, then edited the `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` in `settings.py` to display youtube plugin, but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': 'CMS',
    'toolbar_CMS': [
        {
            'name': 'basicstyles',
            'groups': ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'],
            'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
        },
        {
            'name': 'paragraph',
            'groups': ['list', 'indent', 'blocks'],
            'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote']
        },
        {
            'name': 'links',
            'items': ['Link', 'Unlink']
        },
        {
            'name': 'insert',
            'items': ['Image', 'HorizontalRule', 'Table', 'Iframe', ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'colors',
            'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']
        },
        {
            'name': 'youtube',
            'items': ['youtube',]
        }
    ],
    'height': 400,
    'width': '100%',
    'allowedContent': True,
    'uiColor': '#f0f0f0',
    'extraPlugins': 'link,iframe,colorbutton,autogrow,youtube',
    'autoGrow_maxHeight': 800,
    'autoGrow_minHeight': 400,
    'removePlugins': 'resize',
    'removeButtons': None,
    'contentsCss': ['/static/css/news_show.css', '/static/css/cke.css'],
},
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was just a silly mistake.

```
    {
        'name': 'youtube',
        'items': ['Youtube',]
    }
```

the y in youtube item must be in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to declare into settings.py file then you can also add it to models.py file.See below code:-

```
class Post(models.Model): 

    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True, extra_plugins= 
    ['codesnippet','youtube',], external_plugin_resources= 
    [('youtube','/static/blog/ckeditor_plugin/youtube/youtube/','plugin.js')],)
```

When you download the zip file of youtube plugin from http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube you have to unzip if in your static folder of your project.And add this path to external_plugin_resources as shown in above code.